# How to split ul list into List<string> with li using class or another attribute

Tags: c#, regex, list, html-lists

I have a html `ul` list:

```
<ul>
<li class="ng-scope">Item 1</li>
<li class="ng-scope">Item 2</li>
<li class="ng-scope">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to convert it into `List<string>` in C#. The `li` element can have an attribute or may not have any. Eg. it can be `<li class="ng-scope">` or just `<li>`

I am currently doing so like thi:

```
            string patternUL = @"<(ul|ol)[\s]*[^\>]*>(<li[ a-z=""\\]*>.*?</li>)+?</\1>";
            string trg = Regex.Replace(source, patternUL, (param) =>
            {
                foreach (Capture c in param.Groups[2].Captures)
                {
                    output += $"{Regex.Replace(c.Value.Replace("&amp;", "&"), "<li>(.*?)</li>", "$1")}|";
                }
                //}
                return output;
            });
```

But I don't get the list split into the string List - it doesn't match the pattern.
If I pass ul list with li without any attribute then it works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to parse `html` with regex. Instead use a framework like [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). Doing so you can achieve getting all `<li></li>` as list like that:

```
var html = @"
    <ul>
       <li class=""ng-scope"">Item 1</li>
       <li class=""ng-scope"">Item 2</li>
       <li class=""ng-scope"">Item 3</li>
    </ul>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var list = new List<string>(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li").Select(li => li.InnerText));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use HtmlAgilityPack to parse html :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(File.ReadAllText("test.txt")); // here you can give a normal string
foreach (var li in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")) // select li only
{
    output += li.InnerText; // here do what you want to do
}
```

It captures following texts:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```